# makefiles and using eclipse for Linux programs and C++

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

can anyone point me in the direction of a good tutorial on how makefiles work and also how to start a basic program from scratch using eclipse? I am using eclipse version 3.4.1 for fedora and C++. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Writing Makefiles by hand might not be such a good idea. There are good build systems such as CMake that can do that for you in a far more portable manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CDT](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#C.2FC.2B.2B_Project_Creation) is the plugin used in eclipse for C++ development.  Follow the link for a quick project creation tutorial.  The same link has some information on how Eclipse uses makefiles.